# Where is the best place to associate a 'form display text' with SQLAlchemy mapped property?

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, pylons

In django orm I can use the 'verbose_name' kwarg to set a label that will be displayed in model forms. Now I'm dynamically generating WTForms for each model in a SQLAlchemy mapped backend, but I'm not sure where to associate a display text to use in the auto generated fields for each form. For example, in django I could do this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Enter your username')
    password = CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Enter your password')
```

In SQLAlchemy:

```
class User(Base):
    name = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)
```

In this simple case, how could I associate the texts 'Enter your username' and 'Enter your password'  with the 'name' and 'password' attributes respectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could duplicate that functionality by using the ['info' keyword argument to Column](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/schema.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column).  That would look like this:

```
Class User(Base):
    name = Column(String, info={verbose_name: 'Enter your username',})
    password = Column(String, info={verbose_name: 'Enter your password',})
```

Then you could pull info['verbose_name'] out when you dynamically generate a form.